# webdriver modal window click() not working

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I've been browsing around trying to find a solution to this but none of the solutions have worked for me thus far.

Here is a quick test I've thrown together where its simply trying to click the 'close' button to close a modal pop up. I can step through my test in Visual Studio and it will work fine. When I run the test in Nunit, it will error. I've tried the following based upon others issues and suggestions given to them:-

- putting in waits all over the place
- changing from the chrome driver to firefox
- changing to maximised window mode
- re-working it every which way I can think of

The modal is not an iframe or anything like that. I seem to be getting the following error:

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.InvalidOperationException : Element is not clickable at point (922.5, 342.0999755859375). Other element would receive the click:

which is why I was fiddling with maximised and normal sized modes.

Looking for any suggestions as it's got me stumped..

Thanks

```
[Test(Description = "Test to check if the cancel button closes the modal window when clicked on the 'Reset Password' modal")]
    public void CheckCancelPasswordResetOnModalWorks()
    {
        bool modalFoundSuccess = false;
        bool forgotPasswordControlFound = false;
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(_baseURL + "login");

        if (_loginPage.CheckForgotPasswordControlExists())
        {
            forgotPasswordControlFound = true;

            _loginPage.ClickForgotPasswordButton();

            if (_loginPage.CheckResetPasswordModalIsDisplayed())
            {
                modalFoundSuccess = true;
                _loginPage.ClickCancelResetPasswordButton();
                if (_loginPage.CheckResetPasswordModalIsDisplayed() != true)
                {
                    modalFoundSuccess = false;
                }
                Assert.IsFalse(modalFoundSuccess, "The modal window did not close when the 'cancel' button was clicked on the modal pop up");
            }
            Assert.IsTrue(forgotPasswordControlFound, "Could not find the 'Forgotten Password' Modal box on the page");
        }
        Assert.IsTrue(forgotPasswordControlFound, "Was not able to find the 'Forgot Password' button on the '/login' page.");
    }
```

---

Page Item

```
public class LoginPage : Page
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;
    public string userNameValidationText = "Username must be filled in.";
    public string passwordValidationText = "Password must be filled in.";
    public string incorrectLoginValidationText = "The user name or password is incorrect";

    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "scfForm")]
    private IWebElement _WFFMForm;

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@class='scfSubmitButtonBorder']/input")]
    private IWebElement _loginButton;

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@class='scfSingleLineGeneralPanel']/input")]
    private IWebElement _userNameField;

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@class='scfPasswordGeneralPanel']/input")]
    private IWebElement _passwordField;

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@id='divForgotPassword']")]
    private IWebElement _resetPasswordModal;

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@id='divForgotPassword']/p/input")]
    private IWebElement _forgotPasswordEmailInputField;

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@id='divForgotPassword']/a[contains(., 'Reset My Password')]")]
    private IWebElement _resetPasswordButton;

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@id='divForgotPassword']/a[contains(., 'Cancel')]")]
    private IWebElement _cancelResetPasswordButton;

    [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@class='forgot-password']/a[contains(., 'Forgot Password')]")]
    private IWebElement _forgotPasswordButton;

    public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
        : base(driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
        PageFactory.InitElements(_driver, this);
    }

    public void InputUserNameText(string phoneText)
    {
        _userNameField.Clear();
        _userNameField.SendKeys(phoneText);
    }

    public void InputPasswordText(string queryText)
    {
        _passwordField.Clear();
        _passwordField.SendKeys(queryText);
    }

    public void InputResetPasswordEmail(string resetEmail)
    {
        _forgotPasswordEmailInputField.Clear();
        _forgotPasswordEmailInputField.SendKeys(resetEmail);
    }

    public void ClickLoginButton()
    {
        _loginButton.Click();
    }

    public void ClickResetButton()
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until((d) => { return CheckModalHasLoaded(); });
        _resetPasswordButton.Click();
    }

    public void ClickCancelResetPasswordButton()
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        wait.Until((d) => { return CheckModalHasLoaded(); });
        _cancelResetPasswordButton.Click();
    }

    public void ClickForgotPasswordButton()
    {
        _forgotPasswordButton.Click();
    }

    public void ClickLoginButtonForEmtpyValidation()
    {
        _loginButton.Click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        wait.Until((d) => { return CheckValidationTopBoxExists(); });
    }

    public bool CheckValidationForIncorrectLoginExists()
    {
        return Utility.IsThisElementPresent(_driver, By.XPath("//div[@class='scfSubmitSummary']/span"));
    }

    public bool loginFormExistsCheck()
    {
        return Utility.IsThisElementPresent(_driver, By.ClassName("scfForm"));
    }

    public bool CheckValidationTopBoxExists()
    {
        return Utility.IsThisElementPresent(_driver, By.ClassName("scfValidationSummary"));
    }

    public bool CheckResetPasswordModalIsDisplayed()
    {
        return Utility.IsThisElementPresent(_driver, By.XPath("//div[@id='divForgotPassword']"));
    }

    public bool CheckForgotPasswordControlExists()
    {
        return Utility.IsThisElementPresent(_driver, By.ClassName("forgot-password"));
    }

    public bool CheckModalHasLoaded()
    {
        return Utility.IsThisElementPresent(_driver, By.XPath("//div[@id='divForgotPassword']"));
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be good if you cud provide some html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the modal is already in the DOM(ie. not loaded via ajax) you may need to change it to wait for element visible (assuming the modal is hidden). This is because the element is present always, just not visible. This explains why it works when you step through it in debug mode also.

Try using something like

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//div[@id='ElementYouWantToTarget']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

to me this sounds like either your control lost focus or you did not focus onto right control.
What did you do to find the right control and then have focus on it ?

Comment: Perhaps I need to set the focus as you say. I'm simply waiting for the modal to display and then using selectors as I do for any other page.. How do you usually set your focus for a modal? Don't suppose you have a link for this - I've not found anything overly helpful googling around yet for C# and webdriver it all seems to be out dated stuff.