# Cannot click on the Save button, it is losing focus

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

My script does not click on the Save button. I am using Visual Studio, Selenium Webdriver C#

I have used the following:

```
IWebElement SaveButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='Modal_8595571598015005039Container']/form/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]/span"));
SaveButton.Click();
```

Inspect Element

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-busy-text="Saving..."><i class="fa fa-check"></i> <span>Save</span></button>
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
<span>Save</span>
```

Comment: Is there an error message or exception?   "My code doesn't work" is not a very helpful question.

Comment: Can you share the HTML of your element you want to click ? What do you mean by its loosing focus ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webdriver modal window click() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640151/webdriver-modal-window-click-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

I have use used copy the "Copy Full XPath".

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[4]/form/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]/span"))).Build().Perform();
IWebElement SaveButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[4]/form/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]/span"));
SaveButton.Click();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

Answer (score 0):

Use either of the following **xpath** to click on `Save` Button.

```
IWebElement SaveButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary']//span[text()='Save']"));
SaveButton.Click();
```

Or

```
IWebElement SaveButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[.//span[text()='Save']]"));
SaveButton.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code it might help you out

```
// Displays a SaveFileDialog so the user can save the Image
        // assigned to Button2.
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "html|*.html|lua file|*.lua|text 
document|*.txt|video|*.mp4|image|*.jpg";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "save project";
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        // If the file name is not an empty string open it for saving.
        if (saveFileDialog1.FileName != "")
        {
            // Saves the Image via a FileStream created by the OpenFile method.
            System.IO.FileStream fs =
                (System.IO.FileStream)saveFileDialog1.OpenFile();
            // Saves the Image in the appropriate ImageFormat based upon the
            // File type selected in the dialog box.
            // NOTE that the FilterIndex property is one-based.
            switch (saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex)
            {
                case 1:
                    this.button2.Image.Save(fs,
                      System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    this.button2.Image.Save(fs,
                      System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    this.button2.Image.Save(fs,
                      System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                    break;
            }

            fs.Close();
        }
```