# How to find element in the modal window

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, wdio

I have next modal window:[image]

When I try to work with dropdown or calendar,

```
get partySizeField() {
return $("#sn-reservationSelectorPartySize");
}
async partySizeValues() {
await this.partySizeField.click();
}
```

I get an error

```
Error: Can't call click on element with selector "#sn-reservationSelectorPartySize" because element wasn't found
```

What is the right way to call dropdown in a modal window?

Comment: Are you sure the modal is in the DOM at the moment this code is called?
If not, you might need to wait a bit as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640151/webdriver-modal-window-click-not-working

Answer (score 0):

The element you are after, it is inside and `iframe`.In order to access the element, you need to switch to `iframe` first.

```
const iframeElement = driver.findElement(By.css("div#sn-modal-container> iframe"));
await driver.switchTo().frame(iframeElement);

get partySizeField() {
return $("#sn-reservationSelectorPartySize");
}
async partySizeValues() {
await this.partySizeField.click();
}
```

Comment: I got ReferenceError: By is not defined

Comment: I wrote `const iframeElement = driver.findElement(By.css("div#sn-modal-container>iframe") )`; before describe block, and in the describe block I wrote `await driver.switchTo().frame(iframeElement);` but again got ReferenceError: By is not defined – 
Evgeniya
 10 mins ago    Delete

Comment: If I wrote `const iframeElement = driver.findElement(By.css("div#sn-modal-container>iframe") );` IN the describe block, I get another error `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'iframe' before initialization`

Answer (score 0):

The *Modal Window* elements are within an [**iframe**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to **switch to** the `<iframe>` first as follows:

```
const iframe = $(iframe[src*='preview-sdk.seatninjab/reservation-form'])
await browser.switchToFrame(iframe);

get partySizeField() {
return $("#sn-reservationSelectorPartySize");
}
async partySizeValues() {
await this.partySizeField.click();
}
```

---

### tl; dr

[Switching To Frames in WebDriverIO](https://www.qafox.com/switching-to-frames-in-webdriverio/)

Comment: I got ReferenceError: $ is not defined